# Cannot get relative image path in angular 6

Tags: angular, image, angular6

This is the structure of my folders

```
angular-src
--src
--app
----components
------whatever.html
public
--images
----01.jpg
```

I want to access `01.jpg` from `whatever.html`.

I tried many alternatives like `<img src="../../../../public/images/01.jpg">` or `<img src="../../../../../public/images/01.jpg">` and I keep getting 404.

I use angular 6 and node 8.11.1. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Angualr builds your application around `index.html`. This means the paths are relative to it : try `<img src="public/images/01.jpg">`

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a 404

Comment: Have you declared your `public` folder to be an asset ?

Comment: Nope. I guess this is the problem in the first place. Thanks

Comment: Pretty much ! you know how to do it ?

Comment: Thierry V's answer I guess will do it. Right?

Comment: Kind of messy, but the idea is there. Simply use `"assets": ["src/public"]` (along with other assets folders that you might have) and you should be good to go

Comment: So what is the difference between your code and Thierry's ? What your code does? Setting the `public` as an asset without removing or copying? Thanks

Comment: I think that the answer provided by @ThierryV allows for custom configurations, whereas inputting only the folder simply import all files in the said folder. With his solution, you could for instance load only JPEG files. The link he gave is pretty explanatory, I would suggest you read it to see what fits your best !

Answer (score 3):

In your .angular.json you can define the glob as this [one](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration)

```
"assets": [
    {"glob": "**/*", "input": "../../public", "output": "./assets/"}
]
```

This will copy the contents of your `public` folder to the `/dist/assets/` directory. Then, use it like

```
<img src="assets/images/01.jpg">
```

Comment: I only see an `angular.json` file. Is it the same thing I guess? This is what it contains `"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],`

Comment: @codebot yes, try to put the line glob in assets array

Comment: Oh wait. What is getting "copied" where? In practice , what is in the `public/images` is copied in the final `assets` folder after the angular project is compiled? Then there is no sense, I should save all my photos in the `assets` in the first place, if they will end up there.

Comment: Also where `outputassets` is defined?

Comment: @codebot "copied" simply means that you will keep your files in your original folders, and that they will be copied in your `dist` folder when you build your app (if it didn't, you would lose all your files everytime you build your app).

Comment: Ok, so at least for this case  I will save the images in the `assets` if they will end up there. The glob you suggested is very interesting and I didnt know about it, but I thinks is more suitable for files outside the project. Now I have the option to start saving the files in the project from the beginning. So yeah, I will change my code to save and get images from the `assets` . Thanks for all the info and the conversation

Answer (score 2):

At first you should move your assets like the img you use into the assets folder which is a direct child of src.

You should then be able to call the image directly by 
`<img src="assets/images/01.jpg">`

Comment: I think of that too. But here is my concern : if I compile the whole project, where this folder is going to be? I am used to uploading things "to the server", being the public folder of node. So, I cant upload things to node's folders and I have to do it in angular's folders ?

Comment: @codebot When Angular compiles your project, it reads the assets folders and let them as they are (i.e. not compiled). It then creates a flattened structure with usually 5-6 JS files, an `index.html` file, and your assets folders. But you could upload files to your nodeJS public folder to use them with angular, I just find it less convenient since the assets folders are made for it.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. So...when I build the project in order to upload it, what is inside the `public/images` is copied in `assets`? If this is true, then I should put images in `assets` in the first place. If this false, then I should define `public/images` as an asset and use it