# Angular 6 image path cannot be resolved after ng build

Tags: angular

this is not my first Angular 6 project but I cannot figure out, why my image cannot be resolved after ng build. The image is added in a partial sass file like this:

```
#login-container
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.1), rgba(255,255,255,0.6)),url("/assets/harry.jpg")
    background-size: cover !important
    height: 66vh
```

On the dev server I see the picture on the login screen, after the building though I get an:

```
GET http://marco.codefactory.live/assets/harry.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm building it like that:

```
sudo ng build --base-href ./
```

I also tried these variants for the path:

```
url("/../assets/harry.jpg") //did compile but did not work on webserver
url("./assets/harry.jpg") //didn't compile
url("./../assets/harry.jpg") //didn't compile
url("assets/harry.jpg") //didn't compile
```

I tried also this for the angular.json file found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274691/cannot-get-relative-image-path-in-angular-6):

```
 "assets": [
              { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/assets/" },
              { "glob": "favicon.ico", "input": "src/", "output": "/" },
            ],
```

Didn't change anything. Also putting the lines from the partial sass to the main styles.sass didn't work. The only way to make it work, is by setting the background picture with js, which I don't like, because styling should go to stylesheets and application code should go the typescript files. Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this github issue? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071

Comment: I don't see, how this connects with my problem. I don't have a library assets folder. I actually see see the picture in the dists asset folder, so the picture is actually there, just the link is probably wrong, I suppose. :)

Comment: Did you ever find some solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope, sadly no. Though I wasn't searching anymore.